# How to SCP files which are being FTPed by another process &delete them on completion?

Tags: linux, file, ftp, scp

Files are being transferred to a directory on my machine by FTP protocol. I need to SCP these files to another machine & delete them on completion.
How can I detect if file trasfer by FTP has been done & the file is safe to do SCP?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reliable way to detect completion of the transfer. Some clients send ALLO command and pass the size of the file before actually uploading the file, but this is not a definite rule, so you can't rely on it. All in all, it's possible that the client streams the data and there's no definite "end" of file on its side.

If the client is under your control, you can make it upload files with extension A and after upload rename the files to extension B. And then you transfer only files with extension B.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

EXPECTED_ARGS=1
E_BADARGS=65

#Arguments control
if [ $# -lt $EXPECTED_ARGS ]
then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` <folder_update_1> <folder_update_2> <folder_update_3> ..."
  exit $E_BADARGS
fi

folders=( "$@" )
for folder in ${folders[@]} 
do
    #Send folder or file to new machine 
    time rsync --update -avrt -e ssh /local/path/of/$folder/ user@192.168.0.10:/remote/path/of/$folder/

    #Delete local file or folder
    rm -r /local/path/of/$folder/
done
```

It is configured to send folders. If you want files need make little changes on script as:

```
    time rsync --update -avrt -e ssh /local/path/of/$file user@192.168.0.10:/remote/path/of/$file
    rm /local/path/of/$file/
```

**Rsync** is similar to **scp**. I prefer use **rsync** but you can change it.